# Preciso relacionar duas tabelas de forma a me trazer um resultado dentro das condições que eu quero

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, stored-procedures, procedure

Estou usando o SQLSERVER

Condição(O que o resultado deve me retornar)
· Criação da agenda. Necessário a criação do fluxo para criação de agenda e bloqueio para reserva das vagas;

Ao cruzar os dados de duas tabelas eu preciso atribuir uma vaga para aquele paciente que entrou em contato primeiro. E essa vaga não pode mais ser atribuida a nenhum outro paciente.

[image: As Tabelas estão preenchidas assim]

Para fazer isso pensei na criação de uma procedure, mas não consigo acertar na sintaxe, me ajudem por favor, ou se tiver alguma outra forma de fazer isso também

```
CREATE PROCEDURE OcuparVaga
AS
BEGIN
-- Criando tabela de retorno da proc
    SELECT CodPaciente, NomePaciente, NULL NomeEspecialidade, NULL NomeMedico,Telefone, 
    Celular, NULL DataVaga, NULL HoraVaga, 0 StatusVaga, NULL Obs
    INTO #Retorno
    FROM  Paciente WHERE StatusSolic = 0

-- Declarando variavel para ser utilizada no while
      DECLARE @i INT
        SET @i = 0

-- Tabela temporaria para controle do while
    SELECT * INTO #Solicitacoes FROM Paciente WHERE StatusSolic =0

-- Verificando se existe Pacientes com status igual a 0(disponivel)
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Solicitacoes) ==0
    BEGIN
        RETURN 'Não há Pacientes a serem atribuido a vaga'
    END
-- Iniciando o while
    WHILE @i < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Solicitacoes)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @CodPaciente INT --Variavel que representará a linha da tabela Paciente que estamos executando

----Preenchendo a váriavel com a menor data/hora (conforme definido a prioridade)
        SELECT @CodPaciente = CodPaciente FROM #Solicitacoes
        ORDER BY DataContato, HoraContato

--- Pegar a primeira linha com a menor data/hora dentre as vagas disponíveis para atribuir ao Paciente de acordo com a especialidade, regra de data e statusVaga

        SELECT TOP 1 a.* INTO #Disponivel FROM Horarios AS a
        INNER JOIN Paciente AS s ON a.CodEspecialidade = s.CodEspecialidade
        WHERE a.DataHorarios >= DATEADD(day, 3, s.DataContato)
        AND a.StatusVaga=0 AND s.CodPaciente = @CodPaciente

        DECLARE @CodHorarios INT = 0 --Será utilizada para o preenchimento da vaga
        SELECT @CodHorarios = CodHorarios FROM #Disponivel -- Setar na variável o id da vaga disponível que está na tabela temporária


--Se existir uma vaga disponível, o status da vaga e do Paciente serão alterados
        IF @CodHorarios >0
        BEGIN
            UPDATE Horarios SET StatusVaga = 1, CodPaciente = @CodPaciente
            WHERE CodHorarios = @CodHorarios

            UPDATE Paciente SET StatusSolic = 1
            WHERE CodPaciente = @CodPaciente

            UPDATE #Retorno SET NomeEspecialidade = a.NomeEspecialidade,
                        NomeMedico = a.NomeMedico,
                        DataVaga = a.DataHorarios, HoraVaga = a.HoraHorarios,
                        StatusVaga = 1, Obs = 'Vaga preenchida com sucesso!'
            FROM #Retorno r
            INNER JOIN Horarios AS a ON r.CodPaciente = a.CodPaciente
            WHERE a.CodHorarios = @CodHorarios
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE #Retorno SET Obs = 'Não foi encontrado um horário para a especialidade desejada.'
            WHERE CodPaciente = @CodPaciente
        END
        -- Deleta a linha atual para o while seguir para a próxima
        DELETE FROM #Solicitacoes WHERE CodPaciente = @CodPaciente
        SET @i= @i+1 --Incrementa +1 no indice do while
    END
SELECT * FROM #Retorno
END
GO
```

Comment: Ele informa que sintaxe incorreta e q create procedure deve ser a unica instrução no lote.

Comment: Poderia acrescentar na descrição acima do tópico: (1) quais são todas as regras que devem ser seguidas para a construção do código; (2) o código que cria as tabelas; (3) código que gera a massa de dados para testes.

Answer (score 1):

> *Ao cruzar os dados de duas tabelas eu preciso atribuir uma vaga para aquele paciente que entrou em contato primeiro. E essa vaga não pode mais ser atribuida a nenhum outro paciente*.

O ideal é construir códigos que tratem as linhas em blocos (`data set`) e não uma linha de cada vez (`row by row`). Para tabelas pequenas não faz diferença, mas para grandes volumes o aumento no tempo de processamento é enorme.

Eis esboço de sugestão, que trata da alocação das solicitações de consultas com as vagas disponíveis seguindo a regra “*atribuir uma vaga para aquele paciente que entrou em contato primeiro*”:

```
-- código #1 v4
declare @PacOk table (CodPaciente int, CodHorarios int);

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

with 
grupoPaciente as (
SELECT *, Seq= row_number() over (partition by CodEspecialidade 
                                  order by DataContato, HoraContato)
  from Paciente
  where StatusSolic = 0
),
grupoVaga as (
SELECT *, Seq= row_number() over (partition by CodEspecialidade 
                                  order by DataHorarios, HoraHorarios)
  from Horarios
  where StatusVaga = 0
)
UPDATE gV
  set CodPaciente= gP.CodPaciente,
      StatusVaga= 1
  output inserted.CodPaciente, inserted.CodHorarios into @PacOk
  from grupoVaga as gV
       inner join grupoPaciente as gP on gP.CodEspecialidade = gV.CodEspecialidade
                                         and gP.Seq = gV.Seq;

UPDATE Paciente
  set StatusSolic= 1
  where CodPaciente in (SELECT CodPaciente from @PacOk);

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

-- relata vagas que foram alocadas nesta execução
SELECT H.CodPaciente, P.NomePaciente, P.Telefone, P.Celular, 
       H.CodEspecialidade, H.NomeEspecialidade, H.NomeMedico, 
       DataVaga= H.DataHorarios, HoraVaga= H.HoraHorarios, 
       'Consulta marcada' as Obs
  from Horarios as H
       inner join Paciente as P on P.CodPaciente = H.CodPaciente
  where H.CodHorarios in (SELECT CodHorarios from @PacOk);

-- relata solicitações de atendimento não marcadas
SELECT CodPaciente, NomePaciente, Telefone, Celular, CodEspecialidade,
       'Não há horário disponível para a especialidade desejada' as Obs
  from Paciente
  where StatusSolic = 0;
```

---

Imagem com resultado do teste:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Estrutura e dados utilizados para teste:

```
-- código #2
CREATE TABLE Horarios (
  CodHorarios int,
  CodEspecialidade varchar(20),
  NomeEspecialidade varchar(30),
  CodMedico int,
  NomeMedico varchar(30),
  DataHorarios date,
  HoraHorarios time(0),
  CodPaciente int default 0,
  StatusVaga tinyint default 0
);

CREATE TABLE Paciente (
  CodPaciente int,
  NomePaciente varchar(30),
  CodEspecialidade varchar(20),
  Telefone varchar(20),
  Celular varchar(20),
  DataContato date,
  HoraContato time(0),
  StatusSolic tinyint default 0
);

set dateformat dmy;

TRUNCATE TABLE Horarios;
INSERT into Horarios values
  (1, '004 3/02', 'ALERGIA - ASM', 1, 'Abílio de Barros', '9/5/2018', '7:00', 0, 0),
  (2, '004 3/04', 'CLINICO', 3, 'Roberto', '10/5/2018', '7:10', 0, 0),
  (3, '004 3/02', 'ALERGIA - ASM', 1, 'Abílio de Barros', '11/5/2018', '7:20', 0, 0),
  (4, '004 3/03', 'CARDIOLOGIA', 2, 'Fernanda', '9/5/2018', '7:00', 0, 0);

TRUNCATE TABLE Paciente;
INSERT into Paciente values 
  (1, 'José', '004 3/02', '(11)5789-8547', '(11)92485-6128', '6/5/2018', '7:00', 0),
  (2, 'Maria', '004 3/04', '(11)5789-7857', '(11)9455-6187', '9/5/2018', '7:05', 0),
  (3, 'Hugo', '004 3/03', '(11)5619-8548', '(11)97085-2630', '9/5/2018', '7:30', 0),
  (4, 'Natália', '004 3/02', '(11)5529-3849', '(11)9278-6241', '6/5/2018', '7:15', 0);
```

Comment: Obrigado por esse retorno, ao tentar executar ele me retorna erro nas variáveis @PackOk dos dois UPDATE'S e no -SELECT para relatar as vagas que foram alocadas nesta execução. 

A mensagem diz que: É necessário declarar a variável de tabela "@PackOk"

Comment: Estou pesquisando um pouco, mas não consigo entender, porque ela foi declarada antes de começar a transação. Tentei executar toda a query. Tentei executar somente a linha DECLARE e depois a transação, mas continua me retornando essa mensagem

Comment: @RogérioCristiano A variável de tabela está declarada como @ PacOk mas no código constava @ PackOk. Já corrigi.

Comment: Coloquei uma resposta com as imagens do resultado para ilustrar melhor a query

Comment: Hoje pela manhã houve momento em que efetuei modificação no código #1 v3 mas rapidamente a desfiz. Não sei se você copiou o código #1 v3 neste momento. Na dúvida, renumerei o código; poderia testar a v4? // Simulei aqui os dados, executei o código #1 v4 e o resultado foi correto. Acrescentei na resposta acima a massa de dados utilizada para testes. // Além da regra _atribuir uma vaga para aquele paciente que entrou em contato primeiro_, quais outras existem? Na descrição somente consta esta, mas no seu código percebi que há um teste de 3 dias...

Comment: Tentei com o v4 e ele ainda me trouxe o José como o paciente atribuído a todas as vagas. 

Além de atribuir uma vaga para aquele paciente que entrou em contato primeiro. A data da consulta tem que ser pelo menos 3 dias após a data do contato do paciente, Como o José entrou em contato 06/05, a data da consulta dele tem que ser a partir do dia 09/05.

Dessa forma somente o José e a natalia é para estarem atribuidos as suas respectivas vagas.

Comment: O código #1 foi construído usando a regra “_atribuir uma vaga para aquele paciente que entrou em contato primeiro_”. Com essa regra o código #1 retornou o resultado correto, conforme consta na imagem anexada na resposta acima. // Se o resultado dos seus testes foi outro, provavelmente modificou o código #1 que postei. // A regra “_A data da consulta tem que ser pelo menos 3 dias após a data do contato do paciente_” não consta na descrição do problema. Ela implica em outra abordagem para a solução do problema.

Comment: José, muito obrigado mesmo, verifiquei e realmente eu tinha feito a estrutura errada, fiz de acordo com o que você passou e deu certo. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

@JoséDiz 
Estou quase lá, esse resultado me trouxe:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Paciente José atribuido a todas as outras especialidades

E quando eu mudo a consulta que me traz as vagas alocadas. colocando

SELECT H.CodPaciente, P.NomePaciente, P.Telefone, P.Celular, 
       H.CodEspecialidade, H.NomeEspecialidade, H.NomeMedico, 
       DataVaga= H.DataHorarios, HoraVaga= H.HoraHorarios, 
       'Consulta marcada' as Obs
  from Horarios as H
       inner join Paciente as P on P.CodPaciente = H.CodPaciente
  where *H.CodEspecialidade = P.CodEspecialidade* AND CodHorarios in (SELECT CodHorarios from @PacOk);

Ele me traz, somente a especialidade que o jose solicitou, mas atribuindo a ele os dois horarios disponiveis, onde deveria ser somente a primeira vaga:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]